# Does AIDE support scanning memfd files?

Tags: linux, aide

Happy to be here with my first question!

I am using AIDE for file integrity checking. Today I came across an article which  details a technique to run malware droppers without touching file system, by using `memfd`.

The article can be accessed [here](https://www.sandflysecurity.com/blog/detecting-linux-memfd_create-fileless-malware-with-command-line-forensics/)

Now my question is does AIDE support scanning `memfd`? Searching google did not return much info.

If it doesn't any other system capable of scanning `memfd` file system?

X.